# How can scikit-learning perform PCA on sparse data in libsvm format?

Tags: pca, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learning to do some dimension reduce task.
My training/test data is in the libsvm format. It is a large sparse matrix in half million columns.

I use load_svmlight_file function load the data, and by using SparsePCA, the scikit-learning throw out an exception of the input data error.

How to fix it?

Comment: Please post at least the exception message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sparse PCA is an algorithm for finding a sparse decomposition (the components have a sparsity constraint) on dense data.

<del>If you want to do vanilla PCA on sparse data you should use `sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA` that implements an scalable approximate method that works on both sparse and dense data.</del>

<del>IIRC `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` only works on dense data at the moment. Support for sparse data could be added in the future by delegating the SVD computation on the sparse data matrix to arpack for instance.</del>

**Edit**: as noted in the comments sparse input for `RandomizedPCA` is deprecated: instead you should use `sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD` that does precisely what  `RandomizedPCA` used to do on sparse data but should not have been called PCA in the first place.

To clarify: PCA is mathematically defined as centering the data (removing the mean value to each feature) and then applying truncated SVD on the centered data.

As centering the data would destroy the sparsity and force a dense representation that often does not fit in memory any more, it is common to directly do truncated SVD on sparse data (without centering). This resembles PCA but it's not exactly the same. This is implemented in scikit-learn as `sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD`.

**Edit (March 2019)**: There is ongoing work to implement PCA on sparse data with implicit centering: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/12841

Comment: Do you mean incorrect? Or useless for your task? If you used the `RandomizedPCA` try to play with the number of power iterations `iterated_power` to see if you can improve the results (3 by default, you can try between between 0 an 10 for instance).

Comment: For more details have a look at the reference documentation http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA.html and the linked references.

Comment: For the benefit of other latecomers, RandomizedPCA no longer supports sparse array input. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242215/scikit-learn-sklearn-pca-throws-type-error-on-sparse-matrix

Comment: For the very-latecomers, `RandomizedPCA` has been deprecated. Instead, use `PCA` with keyword argument `svd_solver='randomized'`

Comment: On sparse data, `PCA` with `svd_solver='randomized'` will fail. Instead, you should use `TruncatedSVD` as noted above.

Comment: @ogrisel I have a large sparse matrix and I am thinking of using TruncatedSVD but there's a parameter call `n_iter` in TruncatedSVD which is not present in PCA. What should be the ideal value for `n_iter` and what does it do?

Comment: Use the default. If you do not trust the randomized SVD solver you can try to use the arpack solver and compare the results.