# scipy/sklearn sparse matrix decomposition for document classification

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to do documentation classification on a large corpus (4 mil documents) and keep running into memory errors when using the standard scikit-learn methods.  After cleaning/stemming my data, I have a very sparse matrix with about 1 mil words.  My first thought was to use sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD, but I can't perform the .fit() operation with a large enough k due to memory errors (the largest I can do only accounts for 25% of the variance of the data). I tried following the sklearn classification [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html), but still run out of memory when doing the KNN classification.  **I'd like to manually do an out-of-core matrix transformation to apply PCA/SVD to the matrix to reduce the dimensionality, but need a way to first calculate the eigenvectors.**  I was hoping to use scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs  **Is there a method to do calculate the eigenvector matrix in order to complete the code shown below?**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np
import cPickle as pkl
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

def pickleLoader(pklFile):
    try:
        while True:
            yield pkl.load(pklFile)
    except EOFError:
        pass

#sample docs
docs = ['orange green','purple green','green chair apple fruit','raspberry pie banana yellow','green raspberry hat ball','test row green apple']
classes = [1,0,1,0,0,1]
#first k eigenvectors to keep
k = 3

#returns sparse matrix
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(docs)

#write sparse matrix to file
pkl.dump(tfs, open('pickleTest.p', 'wb'))



#NEEDED - THIS LINE THAT CALCULATES top k eigenvectors   
del tfs

x = np.empty([len(docs),k])

#iterate over sparse matrix
with open('D:\\GitHub\\Avitro-Classification\\pickleTest.p') as f:
    rowCounter = 0
    for dataRow in pickleLoader(f):
        colCounter = 0
        for col in k:
            x[rowCounter, col] = np.sum(dataRow * eingenvectors[:,col])
f.close()

clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10) 
clf.fit(x, k_class)
```

Any assistance or guidance would be much appreciated!  If there is a better way to do this I'm happy to try a different approach, but I would like to try KNN on this large sparse dataset, preferably using some dimensionality reduction (this performed very well on the small test dataset I ran - I'd hate to lose my performance due to stupid memory constraints!)

**Edit:**  Here's the code I first tried to run, that led me down the path of doing my own out-of-core sparse PCA implementation.  Any help on fixing this memory error would make this much easier!

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
import pickle

dataFolder = 'D:\\GitHub\\project\\'

# in the form of a list: [word sample test word, big sample test word test, green apple test word]
descWords = pickle.load(open(dataFolder +'descriptionWords.p'))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_words = vectorizer.fit_transform(descWords)

print np.shape(X_words)

del descWords
del vectorizer

svd = TruncatedSVD(algorithm='randomized', n_components=50000, random_state=42)
output = svd.fit_transform(X_words)
```

with output:

```
(3995803, 923633)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c0db86bd3830> in <module>()
     16 
     17 svd = TruncatedSVD(algorithm='randomized', n_components=50000, random_state=42)
---> 18 output = svd.fit_transform(X_words)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\truncated_svd.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    173             U, Sigma, VT = randomized_svd(X, self.n_components,
    174                                           n_iter=self.n_iter,
--> 175                                           random_state=random_state)
    176         else:
    177             raise ValueError("unknown algorithm %r" % self.algorithm)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.pyc in randomized_svd(M, n_components, n_oversamples, n_iter, transpose, flip_sign, random_state, n_iterations)
    297         M = M.T
    298 
--> 299     Q = randomized_range_finder(M, n_random, n_iter, random_state)
    300 
    301     # project M to the (k + p) dimensional space using the basis vectors

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.pyc in randomized_range_finder(A, size, n_iter, random_state)
    212 
    213     # generating random gaussian vectors r with shape: (A.shape[1], size)
--> 214     R = random_state.normal(size=(A.shape[1], size))
    215 
    216     # sampling the range of A using by linear projection of r

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.pyd in mtrand.RandomState.normal (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:9968)()

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.pyd in mtrand.cont2_array_sc (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:2370)()

MemoryError:
```

Comment: For classification, feature selection might be a better idea than LSA. It aims for accuracy instead of variance.

Comment: `RandomizedPCA` seam to work for sparse matrices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809686/how-can-scikit-learning-perform-pca-on-sparse-data-in-libsvm-format

Answer (score 4):

Out-of-core SVD or PCA *on sparse data* is not implemented in scikit-learn 0.15.2. You might want to try [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) instead.

**Edit**: I forgot to specify "on sparse data" in my first reply.

Comment: Right, which is why I asked if anyone knows a way to calculate the eigenvectors of a non-square sparse matrix.  The code above writes the large sparse matrix to file and then uses a generator so it isn't held in memory.  I just need to derive the eigenvectors so I can be on my merry way.

Comment: Eigen vectors of a non-square matrix does not mean anything. You probably mean singular vectors instead. scikit-learn's `TruncatedSVD` already does that (either using `randomized_svd` or `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds` internally). Both methods are batch (that is non-incremental) though. gensim on the other hand can do out-of-core SVD on sparse bag of words data.

Comment: Ah I had forgotten a step (I needed to get the covariance matrix first - that will be square).  I couldn't get the TruncatedSVD to work out of the box, that's where I was having the memory error, but haven't had time to figure out how to get the batch to work in sklearn.  I'm not sure how I need to store the data on the disk to read it in batch form to the TruncatedSVD function. When I have a little free time I'll have to explore and follow-up

Comment: I update above to show what I first tried to run...any thoughts on that would be helpful, I'm not as familiar with the sparse implementations of sklearn.