# Scikit-learn (sklearn) PCA throws Type Error on sparse matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, pca

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA.html) of sklearn RandomizedPCA, sparse matrices are accepted as input. However when I called it with a sparse matrix, I got a `TypeError` :

```
> sklearn.__version__
'0.16.1'
> pca = RandomizedPCA(n_components=2)
> pca.fit(my_sparce_mat)
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

I obtained the same error using `fit_transform`.

Any suggestion on how to have it work?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that it is not possible to have `RandomizedPCA` work with a sparse matrix with version 0.16.1 of Scikit-learn (current stable version). The documentation I was referring to was for a previous version of Scikit-learn and so alternative functions should be used for the current stable version.

A possible alternative is `TruncatedSVD`

Comment: Thanks for asking and answering this question. There are lots of older discussions out there with outdated info saying to use RandomizedPCA with sparse arrays. I probably wouldn't have easily stumbled onto TruncatedSVD without this post.