# Are these the irreconcilable cons of using DictVectorizer in Scikit learn?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, vectorization, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I have 5+ million data to predict people's race. One textual feature gives rise to tens of thousands more. For example, name 'Smith' give rise to 'sm', 'mi', 'it'... etc. I then need to transform it into some sparse matrix

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer()
X2= vec.fit_transform(measurements)
```

Because of the tens of thousands of generated features, I can't use the following to give me an array, otherwise I am getting an out of memory error.

```
X = vec.fit_transform(measurements).toarray()
```

As far as I can tell, a lot of other functions/modules in scikilearn only allows the array format data to be fitted. For example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA and http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html for dimensionality reduction and feature selection.

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X) # X works but not X2, though I can't get X with my big data set because of out-of-memory error
```

Comment: Do you think it's correct to divide names to such fractions? What is your raw features in task?  Posts texts or what?

Comment: I'd suggest editing the title of your question. It does read like a newspaper headline but is not very informative imho ;).

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain that this will help, but you can try to slice your X2 into smaller parts (but still as big as possible), and use `IncrementalPCA` on them.

```
from sklearn.utils import gen_batches
from sklearn.decomposition import IncrementalPCA

pca = IncrementalPCA()
n_samples, n_features = X2.shape
batchsize = n_features*5
for slice in gen_batches(n_samples, batchsize):
    pca.partial_fit(X2[slice].toarray())
```

You may change that 5 constant to some bigger number, if your RAM size allows to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed you probably won't be able to convert your text features into  a numpy array.
So you'll need to focus on techniques that can handle sparse data.

**PCA is not one of them.**
The reason is that PCA performs **centering of the data**, which makes the data dense (picture a sparse matrix, then substract 0.5 to every element).

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809686/how-can-scikit-learning-perform-pca-on-sparse-data-in-libsvm-format) provides more explanation and an alternative:

> To clarify: PCA is mathematically defined as centering the data (removing the mean value to each feature) and then applying truncated SVD on the centered data.
>
> As centering the data would destroy the sparsity and force a dense representation that often does not fit in memory any more, it is common to directly do truncated SVD on sparse data (without centering). This resembles PCA but it's not exactly the same.

In the context of text data performing SVD after a `TfidfVectorizer` or a `CountVectorizer` is actually a famous technique called latent semantic analysis.

As for the feature selection part, you'll probably have to modify the source code of your scoring function (e.g. `chi2`) so that it handles sparse matrices without making them dense.
It is possible, this is mostly a trade-off between keeping the sparsity of matrices and using efficient array operations.

In your case though I'd try and throw this at a classifier first to see if the extra work is worth your time.