# Pandas/Scikit - Apply sparse PCA while creating feature vectors

Tags: python, r, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am planning to generate a huge sparse matrix of 70000 rows and 150000 columns using Pandas get_dummies(), however I get a MemoryError. How do I apply PCA on this sparse matrix to reduce dimensionality?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809686/how-can-scikit-learning-perform-pca-on-sparse-data-in-libsvm-format). You'll want to use `sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD` to do a PCA on a sparse matrix. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

# create a sparse matrix:
np.random.seed(0)
i = np.random.randint(0, 100, 500)
j = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 500)
vals = np.random.random(500)
M = coo_matrix((vals, (i, j)), shape=(100, 1000))

# compute the sparse PCA
comp = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2).fit_transform(M)
comp.shape
# (100, 2)
```

If your sparse matrix itself is too big to live in memory, you *may* be able to use the `partial_fit` method of [`IncrementalPCA`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA) for online updates, though it only accepts dense input.